# PHP Convert String to an array or object if it represents one

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a function that prints information to the page, it does this because it checks if that value exists every time and outputs an error if it doesn't. Due to the unknown nature of what is being sent to this function it always arrives as a string, I can't change this.

Is it possible for this function to interpret strings such as `"array[0]"` and `"object.something"` and return that value instead of looking for the value as an index in `$this`

E.g.

```
private array = array("stuff");

$this->printValue("string");   
$this->printValue("array[0]");
$this->printValue("object.name"); //Some specified object

public function printValue($key) {
    if(isset($this->$key)) {
        echo $this->$key;
    } else {
        die($key.' doesn\'t exist');    
    }
}
```

Would echo:

```
string
stuff
thename
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this example helps:

```
class Example {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->foo = array(9, 8, 7);
        $this->bar = (object) array('attr1' => 'val1', 'attr2' => 'val2');
        $this->baz = 'abcde';
    }
    public function printValue($key) {
        echo eval('return $this->' . $key . ';') . "\n";
    }
}

$example = new Example();
$example->printValue('foo[0]'); # prints 9
$example->printValue('bar->attr1'); # prints val1
$example->printValue('baz'); # prints abcde
```

However, take into account that [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) poses security risks because it can execute *any* PHP code and it may cause fatal errors. Using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) is safer, though not as general. Anyway, the input of these risky functions must be always validated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bigger question is, are you trying to use `array[0]` as an index for something you're trying to reference?  I'm assuming so, otherwise you could access the data from those items listed.  So, if you ARE wanting to use the `array[0]` as an index-identifier, then you could do something like:

```
private data_array['array[0]'] = "stuff"; 
$this->printValue(data_array['array[0]']);
```

Comment: I am not trying to use array[0] are the index, array is the index and I guess [0] is a sub index. It doesn't work at the moment, isset seems to fail. Many thanks for your time however.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I don't think you can access the data of the original object, since it's no longer an object getting sent.  Anyway to change the `string` getting returned to just pass the object?

Answer (score 0):

im not sure but i think you want `$pie = print_r($var,true)` it sends the string as a return value not printing out